# "react-native eject": Unrecognized command "eject"

Tags: react-native

I am trying to recreate ios and android folders for my react-native project. As far as I know this is done with the command:

```
react-native eject
```

But I get the error:

```
error Unrecognized command "eject".
```

I am doing something wrong? How should I recreate android and ios folders?

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: AFAIK you don't use eject to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It did work in 0.59.9. This threw me too this morning after I upgraded to 0.60. Apparently you now have to run `react-native upgrade --legacy true`. `react-native eject` was much easier IMHO.

Comment: This now no longer works either - `error: unknown option '--legacy'`

Comment: What does it mean?

Answer (score 33):

```sh
npm i react-native-eject
npm i @react-native-community/cli
react-native eject
```

will generate the both android and ios folder

Comment: worked like charm

Answer (score 3):

```
yarn add react-native-eject
react-native eject
```

This two-line of code solved my problem with the eject error.

Comment: don't comments on answer section.

Answer (score 2):

Nikita is 100% correct. If the project was initialized in expo running `react native eject` will "eject" the project from the expo dependencies (and expo environment) and create a standalone react native project outside the expo environment. This typically adjusts the dependencies in the pakage.json file.

The command exists as a part of expo.

To initialize a project from scratch `react-native init` will create android and ios folders. Also ensure if you have cloned the directory to run either `npm install` or `yarn` to install the dependencies.

If the project was initialized the way I imagine yours was the commmand you are looking for would be one of the following:
`react-native run ios` or `react-native run ios --device`
`react-native run android` or `react-native run android --device`

Answer (score 1):

For RN projects, which are initiated by `react-native init` there is no such command, by default RN is using metro bundler instead of web-version of React, where you can configure `Parcel/Webpack/Rollup` or run `create-react-app` where actually you can eject.
This question is suitable for [expo](https://expo.io/) where you can actually eject, if you need some native modules that are not included in expo.

Try to use [expo](https://expo.io/)

Answer (score 1):

`react-native eject` and `upgrade --legacy true` aren't working for me.

In the end, I just created a new blank RN project and this had an ios folder. Copied the folder over to my existing project and ... seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later this is still a problem

for me I keep a copy of the orginally generated folder aside and run

```
cd android
./gradew clean
cd ..
npx react-native start
```

pretty wild that reactNative doesn't have a simple/stable way to regenerate the android folder, something hybrid bundlers achieved over a decade ago..