# What is the alternative to "react-native eject" in React Native 0.60 to regenerate iOS and android folders?

Tags: react-native

I always used `react-native eject` to regenerate iOS and android folders in react native projects before React Native 0.60. But in React Native 0.60 this command is not working. It's giving following error

> Unrecognized command "eject"

Is there any alternative to this command in React Native 0.60.

Answer (score 0):

Now you should use the `react-native upgrade --legacy true` command.

Check this out:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526#issuecomment-510188117

Comment: It looks this command if for upgrading react native version. This is the result after running this command: ` Specified version "0.60.0" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.60.0" semver range. No need to upgrade `

Comment: sir, it's giving same result to me.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526 seems like people having the issue in "0.60.0". Keep an eye on that page. Meanwhile, check the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56922870/11270044

Comment: Please describe,  what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer